# installing issue

Tags: software-center

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 972, in simulate
    trans.unauthenticated = self._simulate_helper(trans)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1096, in _simulate_helper
    return depends, self._cache.required_download, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 235, in required_download
    pm.get_archives(fetcher, self._list, self._records)
SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate a file for the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```